# Traveling Salesman Problem - Eliminating Subtours?

Tags: optimization, traveling-salesman, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to optimize a road trip across the U.S. in an iJulia notebook. I'm currently having issues with subtours. Instead of creating one fluid trip, the solution jumps around from place to place. How could I get rid of the subtours so that my program creates one fluid trip across america. I also would like to have my starting and ending location be at New York City, but I don't know how to do that. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP4JK.png)
[Constraints of program. These make sure you enter and exit each location once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfmtN.png)                           [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAYu6.png)                            [Results of my program. Not one fluid trip, many subtours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEYKe.png)

Tried making constraints so that you enter and exit each location once, but I don't know how to make it a fluid trip with no subtours.

Comment: For a tour, the starting/ending location is totally immaterial. Find a tour and choose the starting point afterwards.

Comment: For just 9 cities, an exhaustive search is quite feasible and you can add any constraint you like.